# Set file permission to files in subfolders

Tags: linux, file-permissions, chmod

Using Linux Fedora 20, being in the parent folder, which contains `a1, a2, a3, ..., a100` subfolders each with two files in it to which I want to assign a new permission, namely `664`. That is I want todo something like `chmod 664 -R *` but this does not work. Subfolders themselves should not be touched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find $parent -type f | xargs chmod 664
```